# Using Rails to get a json object from another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, controller

I have a Ruby script that queries another website that then provides a json file. I'm very new to Rails. I'm using the Heroku with 1 web dyno, and I don't want to add any more dynos.

How do I get Rails to execute this script? Would I do it from the controller?

Will executing the script result in a timeout?

How would I save the json file so that I can do other things to it?

Comment: As you're accessing an external API with ruby, i`d do it inside a method in my model .You have to basically create a method that make a request to the api, get the results and save in your database

Comment: The controller should not have information like this, it should be in the model and tested.  Yes it can time out, 404, 500 etc and you need to account for it in your tests as calling any API can result in error if that service is down.  We like to use RestClient for this and handle exceptions.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll use the controller to call a method in a model, and have the model save the results. Is it the timeout of the website I'm querying that I have to account for? Or, is it the timeout of my own server? Can I have my webpage display a message telling users that it's getting/processing results?